# How to implement multi piece page background that is behind a content background in HTML/CSS without Javascript?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm having trouble implementing this design I was given into HTML/CSS. Here is the .psd: http://www.sendspace.com/file/10wuld

Here is the code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wezW4/

Here are some visual notes:  http://screencast.com/t/FMq6JK5weI

I got stuck now where I used position:relative for #content-background, it leaves a big empty space after I position it.  A friend suggested approaching it differently with absolute positioning on the page background elements, but didn't make as much progress.

How can this be done with my current approach?  Or if my approach is wrong, what is the correct approach?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going with the page-background-clear and slider background stuff. Is there some reason the background-top/clear/and slider can't be one image? Is the slider actually going to slide up and down as they scroll?

Comment: @Vassi Right, those could be combined into a single image.  I split it up so I could use repeating tiles to optimize page load speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
<html>
          <head>
                     <style>
                            #a, #b, #c {background-repeat:repeat-x;}
                            #a {background-image:url(http://dev.enhancetrade.com/prodetails/images/slider-background-5x5.jpg); background-position:center top;}
                            #c {background:white; width: 400px; margin: 0px auto;}
                            #b {background-image:url(http://dev.enhancetrade.com/prodetails/images/slider-background-5x5.jpg); background-position:center bottom;}
                     </style>
          </head>
          <body>
                     <div id="a">
                     <div id="b">
                     <div id="c">
                                adslfijaoifje
                                adslfijaoifje
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                                <p>asdjfoiajoiafeoi</p>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
          </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this concept works.  I had to nest #c inside #b.  And #b inside #c for it to work properly.  Didn't know you could position background images like that. Nice!